# Convert a bitmap into 2D byte array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, 2d

I've been developing a project with using AForge.NET framework. In my project, I've been trying to get 2D byte array from a grayscale bitmap. There are some solutions posted about this subject on this site and other forums. But I've not get the true result. For instance I used that code:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Image img)
{
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Close();

        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

After this "MemoryStream" method, I've thought about converting this byte array into 2D. However, when I tested this code sample with 4*8 bitmap, it returns 1100 values into byteArray. Is that normal? Where am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET `Image` class serves as an interface for two types of images: `Bitmap` images and `Metafile` images. The latter consists of a series of instructions to draw something, not an array of pixels like a bitmap. If you take a look at the [Bitmap class itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx), there's a pair of `LockBits` methods that will let you extract the pixel data for the images. At the bottom of the linked reference for the `Bitmap` class, there's even an example of how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

please use the following method

```
public static byte[,] ImageTo2DByteArray(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        int width = bmp.Width;
        int height = bmp.Height;
        BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[height * data.Stride];
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            bmp.UnlockBits(data);
        }

        byte[,] result = new byte[height, width];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                int offset = y * data.Stride + x * 3;
                result[y, x] = (byte)((bytes[offset + 0] + bytes[offset + 1] + bytes[offset + 2]) / 3);
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You might consider returning the 2D-array in other type than byte since an averaged byte will hide some information. Also consider to include the Alpha-channel (RGBA).

Comment: Do you have to do a marshall copy and then loop through everything and copy it again?  Isn't there a way to have the marshall copy do everything?